# Tomtom ONE disconnecting frequently

Tags: usb, reboot, gps, reset, tomtom

I have a Tomtom ONE GPS device that is constantly rebooting (or whatever) itself when connected to a computer.

I leave it there and from time to time it "restarts" and ejects itself from the computer. The system always complains that the device was not properly ejected.

The problem is not on the USB hub. The device itself changes the screen and starts doing something else. Is there a way to stop this insanity and keep the device on?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you mention a USB hub; have you tried connecting the device directly to the PC's USB port(s)?  have you tried multiple ports (if available)? have you tried disconnecting (all) other USB devices?  (if you haven't, do so and let us know what happens.)

Comment: I have connected it directly to the PC port. The same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Identify the culprit, try another computer to check if the same problem happens there too.

If so, it is either the cable or the device. In that case you will either have to get a replacement cable or let TomTom check the device.

If not, it is the hardware or the software of your computer. In that case you could then try to reinstall the drivers or replace the hardware with one that doesn't suffer from power problems.